# traefik : how to use basic auth when using docker-compose?

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to use traefik with docker compose.

According to the threads I've seen on their site, you could use something like this :

`mytest-steph:
    image: myimage
    ports:
        - "45001:45001"
    labels:
        - "traefik.backend=test_steph"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:test.mydomain.com;PathPrefix:/myprefix"
        - "traefik.backend.port=8080"
        - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=test:$apr1$H6uskkkW$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/"`

But when I launch docker-compose up, I get :

`WARNING: The apr1 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The H6uskkkW variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

Does anyone achieve to use basic auth like that ?

Answer (score 21):

I've found the answer. You have to double every "$" character.

For example:

- "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=test:$apr1$H6uskkkW$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/"

will become:

- "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=test:$$apr1$$H6uskkkW$$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/"

Answer (score 0):

Reformat your labels :

```
labels:
    - traefik.backend="test_steph"
    - traefik.frontend.rule="Host:test.mydomain.com;PathPrefix:/myprefix"
    - traefik.backend.port="8080"
    - traefik.frontend.auth.basic="test:$apr1$H6uskkkW$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you really need to scape the $ char with another $. I tried your provided solution with docker-compose 1.20 but still, it don't works.